# knitr vs. interactive R behaviour

Tags: r, interactive, knitr

I am reposting [my problem](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/576) here, after I noticed that was the approach advised by knitr's author to get more help.

I am a bit puzzle with a .Rmd file that I can proceed line by line in an interactive R session, and also with `R CMD BATCH`, but that fails when using `knit("test.Rmd")`. I am not sure where the problem lies, and I tried to narrow the problem down as much as I could. Here is the example (in `test.Rmd`):

````
```{r Rinit, include = FALSE, cache = FALSE}
opts_knit$set(stop_on_error = 2L)
library(adehabitatLT)
```

The functions to be used later:

```{r functions}
ld <- function(ltraj) {
    if (!inherits(ltraj, "ltraj")) 
        stop("ltraj should be of class ltraj")
    inf <- infolocs(ltraj)
    df <- data.frame(
        x = unlist(lapply(ltraj, function(x) x$x)),
        y = unlist(lapply(ltraj, function(x) x$y)),
        date = unlist(lapply(ltraj, function(x) x$date)),
        dx = unlist(lapply(ltraj, function(x) x$dx)),
        dy = unlist(lapply(ltraj, function(x) x$dy)),
        dist = unlist(lapply(ltraj, function(x) x$dist)),
        dt = unlist(lapply(ltraj, function(x) x$dt)),
        R2n = unlist(lapply(ltraj, function(x) x$R2n)),
        abs.angle = unlist(lapply(ltraj, function(x) x$abs.angle)),
        rel.angle = unlist(lapply(ltraj, function(x) x$rel.angle)),
        id = rep(id(ltraj), sapply(ltraj, nrow)),
        burst = rep(burst(ltraj), sapply(ltraj, nrow)))
    class(df$date) <- c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
    attr(df$date, "tzone") <- attr(ltraj[[1]]$date, "tzone")
    if (!is.null(inf)) {
        nc <- ncol(inf[[1]])
        infdf <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(df), ncol = nc))
        names(infdf) <- names(inf[[1]])
        for (i in 1:nc) infdf[[i]] <- unlist(lapply(inf, function(x) x[[i]]))
        df <- cbind(df, infdf)
    }
    return(df)
}
ltraj2sldf <- function(ltr, proj4string = CRS(as.character(NA))) {
    if (!inherits(ltr, "ltraj")) 
        stop("ltr should be of class ltraj")
    df <- ld(ltr)
    df <- subset(df, !is.na(dist))
    coords <- data.frame(df[, c("x", "y", "dx", "dy")], id = as.numeric(row.names(df)))
    res <- apply(coords, 1, function(dfi) Lines(Line(matrix(c(dfi["x"], 
        dfi["y"], dfi["x"] + dfi["dx"], dfi["y"] + dfi["dy"]), 
        ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)), ID = format(dfi["id"], scientific = FALSE)))
    res <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(SpatialLines(res, proj4string = proj4string), 
        data = df)
    return(res)
}
```

I load the object and apply the `ltraj2sldf` function:

```{r fail}
load("tr.RData")
juvStp <- ltraj2sldf(trajjuv, proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:32617"))
dim(juvStp)
```
````

Using `knitr("test.Rmd")` fails with:

```
label: fail
Quitting from lines 66-75 (test.Rmd) 
Error in SpatialLinesDataFrame(SpatialLines(res, proj4string = 
proj4string),  (from     <text>#32) : 
  row.names of data and Lines IDs do not match
```

Using the call directly in the R console after the error occurred works as expected...

The problem is related to the way `format` produces the ID (in the `apply` call of `ltraj2sldf`), just before ID 100,000: using an interactive call, R gives "99994", "99995", "99996", "99997", "99998", "99999", "100000"; using knitr R gives "99994", " 99995", " 99996", " 99997", " 99998", " 99999", "100000", with additional leading spaces.

Is there any reason for this behaviour to occur? Why should `knitr` behave differently than a direct call in R? I have to admit I'm having hard time with that one, since I cannot debug it (it works in an interactive session)!

Any hint will be much appreciated. I can provide the .RData if it helps (the file is 4.5 Mo), but I'm mostly interested in why such a difference happens. I tried without any success to come up with a self-reproducible example, sorry about that. Thanks in advance for any contribution!

---

After a comment of baptiste, here are some more details about IDs generation. Basically, the ID is generated at each line of the data frame by an `apply` call, which in turn uses `format` like this: `format(dfi["id"], scientific = FALSE)`. Here, the column `id` is simply a series from 1 to the number of rows (`1:nrow(df)`). `scientific = FALSE` is just to ensure that I don't have results such as 1e+05 for 100000.

Based on an exploration of the IDs generation, the problem only occurred for those presented in the first message, i.e. 99995 to 99999, for which a leading space is added. This should not happen with this `format` call, since I did not ask for a specific number of digit in the output. For instance:

```
> format(99994:99999, scientific = FALSE)
[1] "99994" "99995" "99996" "99997" "99998" "99999"
```

However, if the IDs are generated in chunks, it might occur:

```
> format(99994:100000, scientific = FALSE)
[1] " 99994" " 99995" " 99996" " 99997" " 99998" " 99999" "100000"
```

Note that the same processed one at a time gives the expected result:

```
> for (i in 99994:100000) print(format(i, scientific = FALSE))
[1] "99994"
[1] "99995"
[1] "99996"
[1] "99997"
[1] "99998"
[1] "99999"
[1] "100000"
```

In the end, it's exactly like if the IDs were not prepared one at a time (as I would expect from an `apply` call by line), but in this case, 6 at a time, and only when close to 1e+05... And of course, only when using knitr, not interactive or batch R.

---

Here is my session information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.2           adehabitatLT_0.3.12 CircStats_0.2-4    
[4] boot_1.3-9          MASS_7.3-27         adehabitatMA_0.3.6 
[7] ade4_1.5-2          sp_1.0-11           basr_0.5.3         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3    evaluate_0.4.4  formatR_0.8     fortunes_1.5-0 
[5] grid_3.0.1      lattice_0.20-15 stringr_0.6.2   tools_3.0.1
```

Comment: long-shot: `knitr` might change some formatting options (e.g. number of significant digits), somehow affecting how the IDs are generated.

Comment: It might be. But I still do not see what options can affect this output. Let me add more details about the generation of IDs in my first message... See if it makes more sense ! Thanks.

Comment: can you make a minimal example with just this format problem? I don't understand the bit about apply and the white space padding. Do you have 10000 in your list, or not?

Comment: Admittedly, I don't understand it either ! :) But yes, the table is > 100,000 rows, and the IDs generated thus go higher than that too. I already tried to come up with a minimal reproducible example, without success so far (for a reason that I don't understand, the problem vanishes when I reduced that example too much). I'll give it another try and come back here.

Comment: in this specific case, `format()` is not a good choice, since the results can be affected by a number of global options; to faithfully get the character representation of your numbers, I'd recommend you to simply use `as.character()`, then nothing fancy will happen. BTW, I'm glad you followed my suggestion to come to SO. As you have seen, one single author (i.e. me) is much less helpful and responsive than thousands of experts here :)

Comment: Indeed yes, `as.character` instead of `format` solves the issue. The weird thing is that I remember starting with `as.character` and switching then to `format` for a reason. This reason, which I don't remember, is probably not valid any more, since the function is working now as I want. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Ah, now I remember why I used `format` and not `as.character` (and I actually mentioned it in my first post): it's just to avoid scientific formatting, such as `"1e+05"`, which is the result of `as.character(100000)` (and gives me an error if it occurs in the row names). I'll thus stick to `format(..., scientific = FALSE, trim = TRUE)`. R works in mysterious ways...

Comment: @basille sorry I was wrong about `as.character()`; thanks for your correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Aleksey Vorona and Duncan Murdoch, this bug is now fixed in R-devel!

See: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15411

Answer (score 3):

Both Jeff and baptiste were were indeed right! This is an option problem, related to the `digits` argument. I managed to come up with a working minimal example (e.g. in `test.Rmd`):

````
Simple reproducible example : df1 is a data frame of 110,000 rows,
with 2 random normal variables + an `id` variable which is a series
from 1 to the number of row. 

```{r example}
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(110000), y = rnorm(110000), id = 1:110000)
```

From this, we create a `id2` variable using `format` and `scientific =
FALSE` to have results with all numbers instead of scientific
notations (e.g. 100,000 instead of 1e+05):

```{r example-continued}
df1$id2 <- apply(df1, 1, function(dfi) format(dfi["id"], scientific = FALSE))
df1$id2[99990:100010]
```
````

It works as expected using R interactively, resulting in:

```
 [1] "99990"  "99991"  "99992"  "99993"  "99994"  "99995"  "99996" 
 [8] "99997"  "99998"  "99999"  "100000" "100001" "100002" "100003"
[15] "100004" "100005" "100006" "100007" "100008" "100009" "100010"
```

However, the results are quite different using `knit`:

```
> library(knitr)
> knit("test.Rmd")

[...]

##  [1] "99990"  "99991"  "99992"  "99993"  "99994"  " 99995" " 99996"
##  [8] " 99997" " 99998" " 99999" "100000" "100001" "100002" "100003"
## [15] "100004" "100005" "100006" "100007" "100008" "100009" "100010"
```

Note the additional leading spaces after 99994. The difference actually comes from the `digits` option, as rightly suggested by Jeff: R uses 7 by default, while knitr uses 4. This difference affects the output of `format`, although I don't really understand what's going on here. R-style:

```
> options(digits = 7)
> format(99999, scientific = FALSE)
[1] "99999"
```

knitr-style:

```
> options(digits = 4)
> format(99999, scientific = FALSE)
[1] " 99999"
```

But it should affect all numbers, not just after 99994 (well, to be honest, I don't even understand why it's adding leading spaces at all):

```
> options(digits = 4)
> format(c(1:10, 99990:100000), scientific = FALSE)
 [1] "     1" "     2" "     3" "     4" "     5" "     6" "     7"
 [8] "     8" "     9" "    10" " 99990" " 99991" " 99992" " 99993"
[15] " 99994" " 99995" " 99996" " 99997" " 99998" " 99999" "100000"
```

From this, I have no idea which is at fault: `knitr`, `apply` or `format`? At least, I came up with a workaround, using the argument `trim = TRUE` in `format`. It doesn't solve the cause of the problem, but did remove the leading space in the results...

Comment: well, I do not quite understand this, either; perhaps it is documented somewhere, though

Comment: I sent a message to the R-help list, let's see if someone has more ideas about that... https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-July/357642.html

Answer (score 2):

I added a comment to your [knitr GitHub issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/576) with this information.

`format()` adds the extra whitespace when the `digits` option is not sufficient to display a value but `scientific=FALSE` is also specified. knitr sets `digits` to 4 inside code blocks, which causes the behavior you describe:

```
options(digits=4)
format(99999, scientific=FALSE)
```

Produces:

```
[1] " 99999"
```

While:

```
options(digits=5)
format(99999, scientific=FALSE)
```

Produces:

```
[1] "99999"
```

Comment: Quite right! This led me to narrow down the problem as much as I could, and `options(digits = X)` is indeed the trigger of the problem! See my answer below.